# CakePHP routing will not match URL

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I'm attempting to do some custom routing so that my admin panel pages can all coexist under the Admin URL segment. So far, this is not working.

I've got the following rules defined:

**core.php:**

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('landing'));
```

**routes.php:**

```
Router::connect('/admin/landing/:action/', array('controller' => 'admin', 'landing' => true, 'prefix' => 'landing'));
Router::connect('/admin/landing/:action/*', array('controller' => 'admin', 'landing' => true, 'prefix' => 'landing'));
```

I've also tried specifying an action manually and even a completely static route:

```
Router::connect('/admin/landing/edit/*', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'landing_edit'));
```

This also doesn't work.

It's worth mentioning that this Cake site is semi-encapsulated inside a legacy application; as a result the URL hierarchy goes `hostname/pages/controller` instead of `hostname/controller`. I've *also* tried including the `/pages` in the route pattern, but this has had no effect.

**EDIT**: Alright, this appears to be stupidity on my part - an earlier route was unexpectedly pre-empting my newer rule. Thanks to Robert Rozas for pointing me in the right direction via the comments.

Comment: So if you write in your browser something like: yousite/admin/landing/edit/3 ...you have a 404 response or something?

Comment: Actually, it loads the `landing()` method... maybe that's the problem. Going to try reordering my routes real quick.

Comment: My debug-fu is succesfull again xD

Comment: You're a ninja. If you can turn that into an answer (feel free to call me out as an idiot within) I'll accept it.

Comment: Consider it done...feel free to ask, i'm glad to help. saludos ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with routing, you can debug you http petition via web browser, so if you type in your nav something like:

```
yousite/admin/landing/edit/3
```

You can debug the petition, and see if your routing it's redirecting to your desired method. I work a lot with restful api, using Slim as my framework, so i have experience dealing with those routing problems.

Saludos ;)